# Header not displayed for table of contents

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

The headline of my pages should look like this:
[image]
And it is working as suppost for all pages, just not for table of content, table of tabels and the table of pictures.

In this cases it looks like this:
[image]

In my .cls the relevant lines:

```
\LoadClass[12pt,titelpage,a4paper]{article}
\RequirePackage{tocloft}
\RequirePackage{kantlipsum}%Im able to use \section*-titles for headline with automark option
\RequirePackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\setheadsepline[text]{.4pt}[\color{black}]
\lehead*{\headmark}
\lohead*{\headmark}
```

In the main-file for example, I call the table of contents like this:

```
\newpage
\phantomsection %Needed for hyperref
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Inhaltsverzeichnis} %Add toc to toc
\tableofcontents
```

I wanted to provide an MWE - But when I use the exact same defenitions in a preamble, instead of an cls its working as expected.
My professorship want to use my template as standard-layout and I would like to rpovide an cls.
Maby anyone knows, whats causing this behavior.

Greeting
Tristan

Comment: Do not use deprecated macro `\setheadsepline`, especially if you want to use the code as a template for others.  To add the ToC to ToC etc. use package `tocbibind` (if you use a standard class). Option `titlepage` is unknown for class `article`. Therefore: do you really use a standard class? Or a KOMA-Script class? KOMA-Script classes provide options for the ToC entries of LoF, LoT etc. (`tocbibind` is not needed) and `tocloft` should not be used with a KOMA-Script class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that `\tableofcontents` uses `\thispagestyle{plain}`.
My standard solution for this would be something like this:

```
\newpage
\phantomsection %Needed for hyperref
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Inhaltsverzeichnis} %Add toc to toc
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{scrheadings}} % <<<<<<<<<<<<<
\tableofcontents
```

This assumes that `scrheadings` is the desired pagestyle. Otherwise replace it with what you want.

Comment: This is working for the table of contents, but not for \listoffigures and \listoftables. For example: `\newpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abbildungsverzeichnis} 
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{scrheadings}}
\listoffigures`

Comment: If you want to add to the List of Figures use `{lof}` instead of `{toc}` and `{lot}` for the List of Tables.

Comment: makes sense and is working! Thank you both! :)

Answer (score 0):

If pages using page style `plain` should get the headsepline too, add option `plainheadsepline` for package `scrlayer-scrpage`.

Note that your code produces a warning regarding `\setheadsepline`. Its usage is deprecated for `scrlayer-scrpage`. Replace it with KOMA-Script option `headsepline=.4pt:text` and `\addtokomafont{headline}{\color{black}}` instead.

With a standard class you can use package `tocbibind` for the ToC entries of ToC, LoF, LoT etc.

```latex
\begin{filecontents}{myclass.cls}
\LoadClass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\RequirePackage{xcolor}% added
\RequirePackage{tocloft}
\RequirePackage{tocbibind}% adds a toc entry for ToC, LoF, LoT etc
\RequirePackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}% <- added

\KOMAoptions{
  automark,
  headsepline=.4pt:text,% <- changed
  plainheadsepline% <- added
}
\addtokomafont{headsepline}{\color{black}}% <- changed
\setheadsepline[text]{.4pt}[\color{black}]
\lehead*{\headmark}
\lohead*{\headmark}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}% <- to avoid the warning regarding head height
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{myclass}
\usepackage{blindtext}% for dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]